# How to make 2 col-lg-6 remain horizontal in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make 2 `col-lg-6` remain horizontal in mobile view in Bootstrap?

Comment: Could you post a plunker on what you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `col-xs` it will remain same in all view:

```
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
```

You don't need to assign all view classes like this: `class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign class `col-xs-6` to have make two elements horizontal on mobile.
Similarly, if you want the same on tablets and laptops with medium screen, you assign classes `col-sm-6` and `col-md-6` to the element of your choice.

Edit: See [bootsrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for more information on how it works.